# Regex for string that contains a '='

Tags: regex, .htaccess, character

I've tried to create a regular expression that validates a string and checks if it has a `=` character in it.

I also need it to be in brackets like this

```
(.*)
```

in order to retrieve the value later.

What I tried was

```
(.*=.*)
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I match a string that contains a `=` ?

**Edit:**

This is my regex from my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(home|page1|page2|page3|admin)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*=.*) index.php?area=$1&page=$2&content=$3&$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(home|page1|page2|page3|admin)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?area=$1&page=$2&content=$3 [L]
```

Examples would be

`/home/foo/bar` and `/home/foo/bar/page=2`

That's what I pretty much want to achieve. Add `GET` parameters in an eye-candy way. Also, I need to parse if it contains a `=` character, because there are various depths in the web site such as `/foo/page=1` and `foo/bar/page=1`

Comment: can you provide some words to be matched? as an example

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  What doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  What happens and what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this works for me. This call:

```
preg_match('/.*=.*/','foo=bar');
```

returns `1`.

However, if you  just want to check if the string contains `=`, then [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is just enough.

If, instead, it is in the context of a bigger regular expression, the problem may be elsewhere. Please show us the **whole matching pattern** and some sample inputs with the corresponding expected behaviour.

Comment: I've added more info about what I want to achieve with it. It's basically htaccess.

Comment: Okay, now I successfully implemented your regex into my htaccess file. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `.*`, just `/=/` will tell if the string contains `=`.